# looping in a matlab script

Tags: matlab, loops

I am using matlab for part of my final year project. I am solving a geometric series such as the sum of x^j, starting from j=0 up to n-1. I have the following code so far:

```
$Variable dictionary
%N Number of terms to sum
%alpha Sum of series
%x Vector of constants 
%n Loop counter

N = input('Enter the number of terms to sum: ');
alpha = 0;
x = [0.9 0.99 0.999 0.9999 0.99999 0.999999];
for n = 0:N-1
alpha = alpha + (x.^(n));
end
format long
alpha
```

When I run this script it is allowing me to put in the values of x in the script as a vector but asks the user for values of n. Is there anyway I can amend my code so that I can put the n in myself? And make it more than one value of n?

Thanks

Comment: what values you want to pass as n? if for example you have another term for making power (m), the user can enter n and m, and then you can use another iterator to iterate n and m.

Comment: Basically im showing the difference in answer as n increases so i would like to show when n = 10, n =100, n= 1000 and so on

Comment: @user12428 how big is your `x` and `N` going to be. If not too big... then you may not even need any loops.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want (no loops needed):

```
x = [0.9 0.99 0.999 0.9999 0.99999 0.999999];
n = [1 2 5];

alphas = sum(bsxfun(@power, x(:), n(:).')); %'// one result for each value of n
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify this part of code:

```
for n = 1: length(N)
alpha = alpha + (x.^(N(n)));
end
```

And pass the N as vector [10 100 1000]

Comment: You can directly iterate on a list with the Matlab for loop, like shown in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution:

```
x = [0.9 0.99 0.999 0.9999 0.99999 0.999999];
nlist = [10,100,1000];
for elm = nlist
    alpha = alpha + (x.^(elm));
end
```

Comment: Excellent, will try these both! Thankyou!

Comment: This has been helpful thanks but this answer is only solving the first part? It isnt summing all values, where for example n=10 up to n-1.